# List files on device

Tags: python-2.7, directory, device

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to list a directory on a USB device from Windows

```
import os
#dirname = "C:\\temp\\" # works fine
dirname = "\\mycomputer\\WALKMAN NWZ-B133 \\Storage Media\\Music\\"
x = os.listdir(dirname)  
print x
```

There IS a space after B133

Only I get the error
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\mycomputer\WALKMAN NWZ-B133 \Storage Media\Music\*.*'
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to reference a UNC path but are missing some of the escaped backslashes. Try changing dirname to this:

```
dirname = "\\\\mycomputer\\WALKMAN NWZ-B133 \\Storage Media\\Music\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of player is connected via Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) Looks like you need [PyMTP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMTP) Good luck.